# How to use Hadoop Credential provider in Spark to connect to Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, sqoop

I am trying to establish a secure connection between Spark and Oracle as well as Sqoop and Oracle. After my research I have found two different option for two different setup.

1. Connecting Spark to Oracle where passwords are encrypted using **`spark.jdbc.b64password`** and further it has been decrypted in spark code and used it in jdbc url.
2. Using Hadoop credential provider to create the password file and further it has been used in Sqoop to connect to Oracle.

Now keeping password in two different files doesn't seems like a good practice. My question is can we use Hadoop credential provider in spark to use the same credential profile created for Sqoop?

If you have any other option to make this better please help.

Comment: Regarding option 2, you can use a jceks keystore but you'll have to get the password from it as a plain string and add it to your JDBC URL. Moreover, it'll also be visible in the Spark Plan.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use Kerberos authentication both in Spark and Hadoop and with Oracle. The Oracle JDBC thin driver supports Kerberos authentication. A single Kerberos principal is then used to authenticate the user all the way from Spark or Hadoop to the Oracle database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to spark and it would be really great if you can provide more details on how I can implement kerberos authentication?

Comment: You can start by taking a look at these docs https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/sg_spark_auth.html and https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/client-side-security.html#GUID-97E88D18-B590-4313-87B8-EE422DA644B3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use all languages supported by Spark to read the jecks password from inside your code:

Python:

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName("xyz").master("yarn").enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").getOrCreate()
x = spark1.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
x.set("hadoop.security.credential.provider.path", "jceks://file///localpathtopassword")
a = x.getPassword("<password alias>")
passw = ""
for i in range(a.__len__()):
   passw = passw + str(a.__getitem__(i))
```

In the above code you shall get the password string in `passw`

Scala:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProvider
import org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProvider.CredentialEntry
import org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration


val conf_H: Configuration = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val alias = password_alias
val jceksPath = security_credential_provider_path`enter code here`
conf_H.set(CredentialProviderFactory.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_PATH, jceksPath)
val pass = conf_H.getPassword(alias).mkString
if (pass != null && !pass.isEmpty() && !pass.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      jdbcPassword = pass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also allow spark to set `hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` in hadoop configuration in such way:

```py
"""
Create java key store with following command:
> keytool -genseckey -alias duke -keypass 123456 -storetype jceks -keystore keystore.jceks
> export HADOOP_CREDSTORE_PASSWORD=123456
"""
jceks = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "keystore.jceks")
print(jceks)
assert os.path.isfile(jceks)

spark_session = lambda: (SparkSession
                         .builder
                         .enableHiveSupport()
                         .config('spark.ui.enabled', False)
                         .config("spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path",
                                 "jceks://file//" + jceks)
                         .getOrCreate())
with spark_session() as spark:
    hc = spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
    jo = hc.getPassword("duke")
        
    expected_password = ''.join(jo)
        
    assert len(retrieved_password) > 0
```

`spark.hadoop.hadoop.security.credential.provider.path` is little weird but spark cuts off `spark.hadoop.` prefix when loads hadoop settings